# How to seed data in a newly created key in Meteor/mongodb for existing docs

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have just modified mongodb Schema in meteorJS, and trying to access the recently created columns. As there is no data in those newly created columns I can't retrieve the data from the DB. Please help me out in Seeding some blank values to those columns in MeteorJS.

Answer (score 1):

In a Meteor.startup you can run yourcollection.insert({column:""}) to insert a document. Be sure that the fake data is consistent with the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've added a new key called *myNewKey*

You can quickly seed data with:

```
MyCollection.update({ myNewKey: { $exists: false }},{ myNewKey: "foo" });
```